# Finding the derivative of a square root

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the derivative of a pretty simple problem but I just can not force the answer to match the one provided by the book.

$ - \frac {(1+x^2)^\frac{1}{2}}{x}$

I mean it is a very simple problem and I get

$\frac {x^2 (1+x^2)^{-.5} - (1+x^2)^.5} {x^2}$

Comment: You seem to be missing a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$, a $2x$ from the chain rule in the first term in the denominator, and the first factor of the first term in the denominator should be $x$, not $x^2$.  I didn't check your signs.

Comment: @Neal I have 1/2 but it gets cancelled out from the 2x. The denominator should be $x^2$

Comment: If the denominator of the question is $x^2$, the denominator of the answer should be $x^4$.

Comment: You are fine, except you need to put a negative sign in front of the whole thing (or multiply the numerator by $-1$).

Comment: @Neal I meant that the denominator is correct in that x is the original and the derivative is x^2

Comment: I can simplify it down into $\frac {x^2}{(1+x^2)^(.5)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(x) = -\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ where $g(x) = (1+x^2)^{1/2}$ and $h(x) = x$. So you have

$$\begin{align}
g'(x) &= \frac{1}{2}(1 + x^2)^{-1/2}\frac{d}{dx}(1 + x^2) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + x^2)^{-1/2}2x \\
h'(x) &= 1
\end{align}
$$
Then just apply the quotient rule (as it looks like you are doing):
$$
f'(x) = -\frac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{h(x)^2} = ...
$$
EDIT: Note that you could also first rewrite your expression like:
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= - \frac{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}{x} \\ &= -\left(\frac{1}{x^2}(1 + x^2)\right)^{1/2} \\
&= -(x^{-2} + 1)^{1/2}
\end{align}
$$
And then you wouldn't have to use the quotient rule, but could just use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong the derivative should be:
$$\frac{-\frac{1}{2}(1+x^2)^{-1/2}2x\cdot x+(1+x^2)^{1/2}}{x^2}=\frac{-(1+x^2)^{-1/2}(x^2+1-1)+(1+x^2)^{1/2}}{x^2}=\frac{(1+x^2)^{-1/2}}{x^2}$$